# Computing $\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-(4x^2+4xy+5y^2)}d(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Below is a problem in an degree exam in real analysis:
$$\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-(4x^2+4xy+5y^2)}d(x,y)=?$$

The original idea by me is to diagonalize such quadratic form. The result of diagonalization of the quadratic form $4x^2+4xy+5y^2$ is: [image]

However, the eigenvalues are very ugly. How to do the rest step to compute the integral? Is there an easy way?

Comment: where are these problems coming from? I've never seen ones like this

Comment: It's kind of Improper multiple integral. And this was appears in an entrance test for graduate math depart. There're very few real-analysis textbooks I have mentioned this.

Comment: @qbert Would you mind writing an answer? :)

Comment: You can complete the square for $4x^2+4xy$, to write is as $(2x+y)^2 - y^2$. Then you get $(2x+y)^2-y^2+5y^2 = (2x+y)^2 +4y^2$ and the change of variables is now evident.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks. It remind me the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629686/calculate-int-int-e-e5x22xyy2da) I post not long before, but with traditional integration (not an improper one). Can that integral be computed as this way? Why or why not? (The point is that the integral region there is ellipse, I think maybe it is critical?)

Comment: Abstract duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795511/evaluating-dfrac12-pi-int-infty-infty-int-infty-infty-etuv/1795525#1795525

Answer (score 4):

Using the substitution I hinted at in a comment to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2631308): $u=2x+y$ and $v=2y$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-4x^2-4xy-5y^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\frac14\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-u^2-v^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v\\
&=\frac14\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac14\cdot2\pi\cdot\frac12
\end{align}
$$
The polar substitution is $u=r\cos(\theta)$ and $v=r\sin(\theta)$.

Hopefully the test mentioned in your comment to that answer is an old test and not one you are currently taking.

Comment: It's 2014's test. But I'm afraid the same type of question will appear again. :((

Comment: Does this answer make things clearer? If not, what is still problematic?

Comment: I'm going to study and recheck this problem in the library tomorrow, I'll reply then. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to actually perform a diagonalization. If $q(x,y)=a x^2+2bxy+cy^2$ is associated to a positive definite matrix $Q=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}$, then $Q=J^{-1} D J$ where $J^{-1}=J^T$ and $D$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2>0$ of $Q$. By performing the substitution $J(x,y)^T = (X,Y)^T$ we have

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-q(x,y)}\,dx\,dy &=&\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-(x,y)Q(x,y)^T}\,dx\,dy\\&=&\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-(x,y)J^{-1} D J(x,y)^T}\,dx\,dy\\&=&\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-(X,Y)Q(X,Y)^T}\,\left|\det J^{-1}\right|dX\,dY\\&=&\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-(\lambda_1 X^2+\lambda_2 Y^2)}\,dX\,dY\\\small{\left(X=\tfrac{u}{\sqrt{\lambda_1}},Y=\tfrac{v}{\sqrt{\lambda_2}}\right)}\quad&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-u^2-v^2}\,du\,dv\\(\text{Fubini})\quad&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det Q}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-u^2}\,du\right)^2\\&=&\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\det Q}}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and a similar identity holds for $\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}e^{-q(x,y,z)}\,dx\,dy\,dz$, for instance. The elements of $J$ or the exact values of $\lambda_j$ do not really matter, just the positive definiteness is needed to ensure convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Your quadratic form is given as:

$$\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{Px}$$

Now use the substitution (for a justification see below)

$$\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{V}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1/2} \boldsymbol{w} ,$$

in which $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{P}$ and $\boldsymbol{V}$ is the matrix containing the normalized eigenvectors associated with $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$. Note, that in your case you can choose the eigenvectors in such a fashion that $\boldsymbol{V}$ is orthonormal. Then do the substitution of the integral by using the [determinant of the Jacobian for this substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables).

Edit: In order to solve the problem, you will need to determine the Jacobian of the substitution

$$\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{V}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1/2} \boldsymbol{w}$$

as this is a linear expression the Jacobi determinant is given by

$$\det \left[\boldsymbol{V}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1/2}\right].$$

The integral is then given by

$$\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{w}}\det \left[\boldsymbol{V}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1/2}\right]d\boldsymbol{w}=\det \left[\boldsymbol{V}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1/2}\right]\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{w}}d\boldsymbol{w}.$$

The last expression is a well-known result obtained by Laplace by applying a more general formula of Euler (it is often not correctly referred as the Gauss integral). It can be solved by the trigonometric substitution

$$\boldsymbol{w} = \begin{bmatrix}r\cos \varphi\\ r \sin \varphi\end{bmatrix} \implies d\boldsymbol{w} = rdrd\varphi.$$

---

In order to motivate my answer, we will do this step by step.

From the eigenvalue equation in matrix form and the orthonormality of $\boldsymbol{V}$

$$\boldsymbol{PV} = \boldsymbol{V\Lambda}$$

we can obtain

$$\boldsymbol{\Lambda} = \boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{PV}=\boldsymbol{V}^T\boldsymbol{PV}.$$

If we transform our quadratic form by the substitution 
$$\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{Vz}$$

we obtain

$$\boldsymbol{z}^T\boldsymbol{V}^T\boldsymbol{PVz}=\boldsymbol{z}^T\boldsymbol{\Lambda z}.$$

Now to transform the diagonal matrix $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ into the identity matrix we use

$$\boldsymbol{z}=\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1/2}\boldsymbol{w}$$

if we apply this to the transformed quadratic form we can obtain

$$\boldsymbol{z}^T\boldsymbol{V}^T\boldsymbol{PVz}=\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-T/2}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1/2}\boldsymbol{w}.$$

As $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ is a diagonal matrix

$$\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-T/2}=\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1/2}.$$

$$\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-T/2}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1/2}\boldsymbol{w}=\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1/2}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1/2}\boldsymbol{w}=\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1/2}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{1/2}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{1/2}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1/2}\boldsymbol{w}=\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{w}.$$

So we really obtain a simple quadratic form. Chaining both substitutions gives

$$\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{V\Lambda}^{-1/2}\boldsymbol{w}$$

as was proposed previously.

Comment: This is almost certainly what is intended.

Comment: @qbert: I know it is an overkill for this question, but it is a general procedure that should work because it is transforming the ellipsoid into a sphere. Then you can use the parametrization of the associated hypersphere to solve the integral.

Comment: I appreciated seeing it! +1

Comment: @MrYouMath Can you write a detail solution (correspoding to your original answer)? I'm very deeply stucking here :(. Many thanks!

Comment: @Eric: Added more details in the answer. The explicit calculations are up to you :D.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = \pmatrix{2 & 1 \\0 & 2}$, so that $A(x, y) = (2x + y, 2y)$. Then making the substitution $(u, v) = A(x, y)$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\, dx\, dy\; e^{-(4x^2 + 4xy + 5y^2)} 
= \frac{1}{\det A}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\, du\, dv\; e^{-(u^2 + v^2)},
\end{align*}
which should be clear.

Comment: How do you know it should be pick $A = \pmatrix{2 & 1 \\0 & 2}$?

Comment: It gives $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-x^2 -y^2}$, which is a standard integral.

Comment: Is there a general idea to get such matrix? e.g. how to do with $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ or $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey$

Comment: I mean, it's just completing the square. Analysis isn't a toolbox of algorithms to use for problems that match a given type; use the fact that you know how to compute the similar integral $\int e^{-x^2 - y^2}$ and work out the right substitution to put it into that form.