# Double integral over a rotate ellipse domain

Tags: integration, rotations

Calculate:

$\int\limits_R\!\!\int e^{-(x^2+xy+y^2)} dxdy  $

where R is the region $ x^2 + y^2 + xy \le 1 $ .

I have tried to applied the polar coordinates followed by a rotation matrix, but the integrand kept looking like this $ e^{{\sin^2{\theta}}} $

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2631447/computing-int-bbb-r2e-4x24xy5y2dx-y/2631690#2631690

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An isometry maps $x^2+xy+y^2$ into the diagonalized quadratic form $\frac{3}{2}X^2+\frac{1}{2}Y^2$ and

$$\iint_{3X^2+Y^2\leq 2}\exp\left(-\frac{3}{2}X^2-\frac{1}{2}Y^2\right)\,dX\,dY =\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\iint_{u^2+v^2\leq 1}e^{-u^2-v^2}\,du\,dv$$
equals
$$ \frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{1} \rho e^{-\rho^2}\,d\rho = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}(1-e^{-1}).$$

Comment: That's a new trick for me, thank you ! How to get this values, 3/2 e 1/2 ? Thanks

Comment: I got this! Diagonalization ! Eigenvalues! Thanks a lot!